# Problem with function declaration, K&R problem 1-15

Tags: c, function, declaration

Originally there was a problem to Fahrenheit to Celsius for multiple values of Fahrenheit.
Now in problem 1-15 we have to use a function for this task.
Following is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

float temp_conv(float n);

int main()
{
    float lower, upper, step;
    int i;

    lower= 0;
    upper= 300;
    step= 20;
    
    for(i=0; i<=(upper-lower)/step; ++i)
        printf("%5.1f\t%6.2f\n", i*step, temp_conv(i*step));
}

float temp_conv(float n)
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    
    celsius= (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32.0);

    return celsius;
}
```

And is producing the following output:

```
  0.0   -17.78
 20.0   -17.78
 40.0   -17.78
 60.0   -17.78
 80.0   -17.78
100.0   -17.78
120.0   -17.78
140.0   -17.78
160.0   -17.78
180.0   -17.78
200.0   -17.78
220.0   -17.78
240.0   -17.78
260.0   -17.78
280.0   -17.78
300.0   -17.78
```

I am passing different values in function temp_conv, but then too it is producing the converted value of 0 Fahrenheit. Maybe there is some problem with the function, but then how it is computing the Celsius value for 0 Fahrenheit?

Please help.

Comment: What is the variable `fahr` for? Is it supposed to be the argument `n` really?

Comment: Another couple of notes: You don't need the temporary variable `celsius`, you could just do `return 5.0 / 9.0 * (n - 32.0);` And the loop in the `main` function, I would probably do it as `for (float current = lower; current <= upper; current += step)`, and then pass `current` to the f unction.

Comment: There should have a been a compiler warning like "uninitialized local variable 'fahr' used".Watch out for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float temp_conv(float n) {
    float fahr, celsius;
    celsius = (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32.0);
    return celsius;
}
```

You ignore the argument `n` that you passed to the function and calculate `celsius` from `fahr`. `fahr` is uninitialized (there is no `fahr = something`), it is having some uninitialized garbage value that just so happens to result in `-17.78`.

Just calculate it from the argument instead:

```
float temp_conv(float n) {
    float celsius;
    celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (n - 32.0);
    return celsius;
}
```

or with better naming:

```
float temp_conv(float fahr) {
    float celsius;
    celsius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
    return celsius;
}
```

or really just:

```
float temp_conv(float fahr) {
    return (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahr - 32.0);
}
```